# Проект .Net Framework

Tags: .net

Создал программу, используя NetFramework 4.0. На другом компе при запуске пишет, что нужно этот самый NetFramework установить. Можно ли как-то всунуть в мою программу нужные библиотеки, чтобы программа запускалась на всех компах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Достаточно добавить [пакет установки .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/ru-ru/details.aspx?familyid=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7) в набор распространяемых файлов. Еще более правильный подход - это добавить требование со ссылкой на загрузку в пакет инсталлятора msi.

Comment: ещё вариант - использовать более ранний фреймворк - 3.5 практически у всех уже стоит с семёркой